# ffmpeg 360 Video - Convert EAC (Youtube) to Equirectangular

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

I have this top-bottom 360 Video, where the bottom is rotated 90 degrees clockwise, and I am looking for the ffmpeg command to produce a singular equirectangular output. I've been experimenting with various [ffmpeg 360 filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#v360), but am really just guessing at this point.

[image]

Edit:

I thought that the image was stereo so was playing with filters like `in_stereo=sbs`, but it turns out this is just the layout for EAC.

Comment: Would be helpful for your question to add in the ffmpeg command you are currently using.

Answer (score 2):

This conversion requires a [360 video filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#v360), I found the answer on [this wiki](https://wiki.davidl.me/index.php?title=FFmpeg&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop#Converting_EAC_to_equirectangular).

`-vf "v360=eac:equirect"`

full example:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "v360=eac:equirect" output.mp4`